# How do I handle information in Investigations without "bottlenecking" clues?

Tags: gm-techniques, investigation

I'm playing a "Monster of the Week" style campaign with friends based on shows like *Supernatural* but with lots of gritty combat, using Savage Worlds as our system because of the fighting scenes.

I've used some horror "Savage Tales" for our Plot Point Campaign. The adventures don't have an "If the players fail the check" scenario, which is kinda hard to create for me since Savage Tales usually give "important" information this way.

I've also tried to hand them the important information without rolls, but that makes scenes less meaningful, and the roleplay part drags on too much; if Savage Tales are somewhat linear this "hand them info" solution just makes them completely pointless.